# how to get time difference in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two times start_time and end_time, and I want to get the difference in seconds between start_time and end_time, means if start_time=1:1:0 and end_time=1:2:3 then I should get 63.
Please tell what query of MySQL should I apply for this.

Answer (score 1):

`TIMESTAMPDIFF()` will give you what you want:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time) as timediff from `sometable` WHERE...
```

MySQL reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Answer (score 0):

I would have just commented this, but just joined. In his requirements, the start time is in the past, but the result is a positive time difference. so

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time)...
```

should be

```
SELECT ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time))...;
```

Full example

```
SET @startDate = NOW() - INTERVAL 63 SECOND;
SET @endDate = NOW();

SELECT ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate)) AS time_difference;
-- or this
SELECT ABS(TO_SECONDS(@startDate) - TO_SECONDS(@endDate)) AS time_difference;
```